# Silverlight 4 Late bound operations cannot be performed... and no examples help?

Tags: silverlight, linq, reflection, tree, expression

I have tried all variaions that I can find others using, and frankly they all seem to boil down to what I already have.

I want a generic system for invoking methods based on generic inputs. Not sure that really captures it fully, but not sure how to state it.

Here we go:

I want to make breadcrumbs from a params of Expression>

here, SelectedDivisions is ObservableCollection and ModelId is long?.
So, the point is that I want to feed in a list of varying properties, have them processed by the data class such that each is processed by the appropriate method inside of data

```
data.MakeBreadCrumbs(() => dc.SelectedDivisions, () => dc.ModelId);
```

data contains the following code:

```
public void MakeBreadCrumbs(params Expression<Func<object>>[] propertyExpressions) {
foreach (Expression<Func<object>> propertyExpression in propertyExpressions) {
    MemberExpression member = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null) {
        UnaryExpression uExp = propertyExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        member = uExp.Operand as MemberExpression;
    }

    PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    Type[] propTypes = propInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();/
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(BreadcrumbData).GetGenericMethod("MakeBreadCrumb", new Type[] { propInfo.PropertyType, typeof(string) }); //
    if (methodInfo.IsGenericMethod) {
        methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(propTypes[0]);
    }

    ConstantExpression ce = Expression.Constant(propertyExpression.Compile().Invoke());
    string criterionName = ReadCriterionName(propertyExpression);

    methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { ce.Value, criterionName });
}
```

the last line fails with "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true." when I am processing the property expression for the ObservableCollection item.

Here are the methods defined in the data class which are available, and which are correctly selected, but the one for the ObservableCollection fails on invocation

(LookupTypeBase is a class particular to my solution, but insert any type here that works with the type of a fake ObservableCollection property)

```
public void MakeBreadCrumb<T>(ObservableCollection<T> selections, string criterionName) where T : LookupTypeBase {...}
public void MakeBreadCrumb(long? value, string criterionName) {...}

public static class xxx {
public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(this Type type, string name, Type[] parameterTypes) {
    var methods = type.GetMethods();
    foreach (var method in methods.Where(m => m.Name == name)) {
        var methodParameterTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
        if (methodParameterTypes.SequenceEqual(parameterTypes, new SimpleTypeComparer())) {
            return method;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private class SimpleTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Type> {
    public bool Equals(Type x, Type y) {
        return x.Assembly == y.Assembly && x.Namespace == y.Namespace && x.Name == y.Name;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Type obj) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's silverlight 4 so you have latebound method invocation with the dynamic keyword, which should make this easy and fast:

```
BreadcrumbData.MakeBreadCrumb((dynamic)ce.Value, (dynamic)criterionName);
```

Aside from that i think your issue is that `MakeGenericMethod` returns a new `methodinfo` which you ignore instead of keeping around like so:

```
if (methodInfo.IsGenericMethod) {
        methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(propTypes[0]);
}
```